# How to get Zoom to autopopulate phone number when clicking on "tel" number?

Tags: zoom-meeting

I have a hyperlink to a number that looks like `tel+ 1-564-123-4567` . When I click on the link it opens up Zoom but it doesn't autopopulate the number. I am on Windows 10 and have already changed the setting inside "Choose default apps by protocol" to be Zoom for `URL:tel` and Zoom does open, but it fails to populate the number. Any help is appreciated.

Note: This is not for Zoom meetings, just regular Zoom calls. My company has our Zoom linked to our hard phone.

Comment: Have you spoken with your IT staff regarding this?

Comment: No, but that's probably a good idea of where to start. They might be able to figure it out better than I can. Thanks!

Comment: They also have control of your device and so advice we give may not be actionable, even if it is the "correct" answer, due to policies or limits or configuration applied to your systems by IT. For this reason, questions dealing with hardware and software controlled by organizational IT are generally off-topic here. Good job asking questions, just note that in this case there are people paid to maintain your systems and responsible for making sure they work appropriately for your needs, and these are the people you should go to for support on those systems.